# Get Customer Details by Wishlist Product Id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, customer, wishlist

A list of products was added to wish-list by the number of customers and I need to know that which customer was added a particular product to the wish-list, based on the product id.

I need to get the customer details or at-least a customer id based on the product id.

Comment: This's your custom function or core magento. In module-wishlist, you can get customer id based on the product id by join 2 tables wishlist and wishlist_item

Comment: [https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Get-Customer-Details-by-Wishlist-Product-Id/m-p/117440/highlight/false#M6756]

Comment: Hi @AdityaShah the below example code wishlist->getItem doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worked code for me as below:

First iam getting the collection from the wishlist_item table and filter with my product id.

```
$wishlistItemCollection = $objectManager->get('Magento\Wishlist\Model\ResourceModel\Item\Collection')->addFieldToFilter('product_id', ['eq' => $productId]);
```

Then joined the wishlist_item and wishlist table using the common field name wishlist_id and gets the customer_id into the wishlistItemCollection

```
$joinConditions = 'main_table.wishlist_id = wishlist.wishlist_id';
    $wishlistItemCollection->getSelect('*')->join(
             ['wishlist'],
             $joinConditions,
             []
            )->columns("wishlist.customer_id");
```

Using the customer_id we can get all the customer details as below:

```
    foreach($wishlistItemCollection as $wishlistData){
        $customerId = $wishlistData->getCustomerId();
        $customer = $this->_customer->load($customerId);
        $customerData = $customer->getData();
        $customerName = $customer->getFirstname();
        $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Get data by Item ID

```
private $wishlist;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Wishlist $wishlist
) {
    $this->wishlist = $wishlist;
    ...
}

...
$item_id= 1;
$wishlistItem_collection = $this->wishlist->getItem($item_id);
```

> This will return Item data collection including customer ID.

**[Wishlist Model](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2/app/code/Magento/Wishlist/Model/Wishlist.php)**